# How to multithread a session?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I am trying to multithread my python script, which works with mysql via sqlalchemy with "threading" module

```
from threading import Thread
```

But multiple calls are crushing mysql.

If I get it right, the cause of this is the fact that the session object is designed to take  care of only one call at the  time,  so I tied to implement a scoped session approach with the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


s_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
session = s_session()
```

Now I get the following error:

> "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
>   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, >'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

How to fix the problem?

- maybe I need multiple engines to implement scoped_session?
- maybe I need to close session?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you using it? I'll note that the step of calling `s_session` to create the real session is supposed to occur within the thread that uses it; I suspect `session` itself in this case is going to be the thread-local session for the main thread, and trying to reuse it in multiple threads is a bad idea (it effectively undoes the benefit of `scoped_session`). Only reason I'm not posting this as an answer is that I'm not 100% sure of it (only about 95%, but I have no means of testing locally).

Comment: Even in multithreaded projects I worked with, there's usually only one thread governing the connection to the database. It doesn't make much sense to multithread database access, it's a bottleneck and wont benefit from multithreading... In addition, Python itself does not support real multi core threading, it does support "multithreading" in a sense but those threads do not run in parallel. If you're just trying to avoid hiccups of having to wait for MySQL to respond to a query, try asynchronous calls.